# Programmatically detect convergence and divergence of two lines

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, artificial-intelligence, detection

Given two sets of data over the same interval, I can plot them in the same X-Y graph and can check visually if the two lines converge, diverge or remain 'detached' or 'disconnected' over the interval. The sketches below give some idea of what I mean by each scenario. The first is convergence, the second is divergence, and the last one is disconnection. As seen, the data are nonlinear.

[image: converge]
[image: diverge]
[image: detached]

Given a large collection of such pairs of datasets (the intervals are always the same), what would be a reliable and efficient way to programmatically decide which scenario a pair of dataset belongs to?

A possible (but likely buggy) method is to: 1. divide the interval into halves; 2.count the number of intersections between two lines in each half; 3. if the number of intersections in the first half is far fewer than that in the second half, then two lines converge; conversely, the two lines diverge; if no intersection in both the first and the second halves, then the two lines remain detached.

Any suggestion for a better alternative?

Comment: Do you want to find the solution for given interval or for extended interval too? Like I can think of performing quantization on data to near linear form and find the slopes. If they are inclined to each other they are likely to meet in future if they are diverging they will not meet. But I am not sure if this is what you want to find out.

Comment: @SaurabhJinturkar, for a given interval only. It's always the same interval for all the datasets, so the x-axis stays the same and y-values vary between datasets.

Comment: This is not a well-defined problem because you have either lack a objective definition of convergence, or far too little data (finite amount of samples where you need the entire function) to apply it. Your correctness criteria is your gut feeling. That is fine, many AI problems are like that, but be aware that it means rating heuristics requires manual human labor and is rather dependent on the human.

Comment: @delnan, honestly, i wasn't entirely sure if strictly only AI would help solving the problem, except that I suspect my problem may (somewhat) link to pattern recognition. Could you suggest the relevant technique/method from AI that may help? In addition, is there anything else outside of AI that may also help?

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the values from one of the lines from the one from the other one. Now form equal sized slices on the X-axis (maybe 3-5 of them) and summarize all values in each slice. If the slices tend to get smaller they are converging. If the slices tend to get larger, they are diverging. You can also firstly check for intersections to discern conversion and diversion from detachment.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, found it useful. Please suggest if there's any function / code for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a subtraction and a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Just a few suggestions based on the previous comments :

General method would be to do some regression on the curve X[i],Y[i] where 0 <= i <= n (for some well chosen n -- see below), X[i] = X_min + (i/n) * (X_max - X_min)   (where your X interval was X[max], X[min]), and Y[i] is the value of the difference btw the blue and the green curve for the abscisse X=X[i].

If your datas are noisy you may want to clean that noise a little bit first by defining Y[i] as the average over abscisses in the range X[i]-delta, X[i]+delta.

Then you want to fit the curve X[i], Y[i] with something. Here is really the crucial step. I would note recommend fitting with a straight line as this seems quite contrary to the notion of convergence.

You can try an exponential function A*Exp[lambda *x] and then you would say that for lambda < lambda_1 curves converge, lambda_1 < lambda < lambda_2 curves stay disconnected and lambda > lambda_2 curve diverge. In the ideal word without noise and with infinite N you would just take lambda_1 = lambda_2=0 but here you need to allow for some slack, I would think at least lambda_1 <= -1/n and lambda_2 >=1/n. Best solution here is to play a bit with your algorithm and to set lambda_1, lambda_2 as works the best.

The good thing with the previous fit is that it corresponds to a linear fit for the curve X[i], log(|Y[i]|) so you can easily compute it.

However, this exponential fit is just one possibility. You could also try something like a polynomial of the form y = a*x^b. However fitting may be more involved here.

Comment: as for fitting the curve part, why 'fitting with a straight line' is not a good idea? For example, if the two curves converge, then the slope of the straight line would be negative, wouldn't that solve the problem without complicating it?

Comment: How would you differentiate this from the case where the two lines cross ? Or maybe this cannot happen ?

Comment: it is possible the two lines cross/intersect when they converge, and possibly multiple times as long as the difference in `Y` remains small. But, I don't need to differentiate it from the case where they converge but never cross/intersect. As long as the difference in `Y` decreases sufficiently as `X` increases, I will consider the two curves converge. I realize that I haven't define 'sufficiently' here, and I guess it can be something *relative to* the difference in `Y` before convergence. Would like to hear your thoughts on this one.